# OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `teams` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After several hours. Research in StackOverflow. There are a lot of articles about this issue. But I can't figure out what I'm wrong here.

My code:

models/Team.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const teamSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, minLength: 1, required: true },
  description: { type: String },
});

mongoose.model('teams', teamSchema);
```

models/Division.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const divisionSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, minLength: 1, required: true },
  description: { type: String },
});

mongoose.model('teams', divisionSchema);
```

And I was required in index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require('./config/keys');

require('./models/Team');
require('./models/Division');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

require('./routes/teamRoutes')(app);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
```

routes/teamRoutes.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Team = mongoose.model('teams');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get('/api/teams', async (req, res) => {
    const teamsList = await Team.find({});
    res.send(teamsList);
  });
};
```

If I delete `require('./models/Division');`, It works. Why is that?
If not, I got the error:

```
throw new mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name);
  ^
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `teams` model once compiled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mongoose.model('teams', divisionSchema);
```

'teams' should be 'division' in models/Division.js I guess

Comment: Thank you, Martial.